# how to get my plugin content in front end

Tags: php, wordpress

i have created a plugin `A` form to capture name, email and description and store it in database" it is working fine .  i can see it in

```
    dashboard==>settings
```

and functionality is working fine .my question is how to display that form in frontend  website? could any one help me out.

Comment: You answered your own question but it's like it's been written by someone other than yourself to you?

Comment: i have changed it . thanks for your comment  which made  to do the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using shortcode concept i got  the content what i am  expecting .

> add_shortcode('any name ', 'function name');

i placed the above line of code in my script in order to generate the shortcode
i used that short code in my  page as

> [any name]

i got my content in front end .please provide possible ways to do the same .thank you